# How can i use the value of one variable to call another in python?

Tags: python, pygame

So i'm working in pygame and right now, the only way to ensure that everything stays in the right spot on the screen is to check every possible location until it finds the right one for the picture im working on. Then it does the same for the next picture until everything is loaded.

Because pygame runs in lines per second, my code needs to be as short as possible.

What im wondering is if i could take my dessert_rand variable, and use it directly in a statement to call a certain variable, based on it's value. For example:

```
screen.blit(wood, (spot_(wood_rand)x, spot_(wood_rand)y).
```

I know that formatting isn't correct, but that's the general idea of what i want to do. It would allow me to shorten what is currently taking 12 lines down to 1.

```
    wood_rand = randint(1,6)

    spot_1x = 0
    spot_1y = 200

    spot_2x = 100
    spot_2y = 350

    spot_3x = 300
    spot_3y = 350

    spot_4x = 400
    spot_4y = 200

    spot_5x = 300
    spot_5y = 50

    spot_6x = 100
    spot_6y = 50

    spot_7x = 200
    spot_7y = 200

    #Wondering if there's a way to make this all shorter...

    #Somthing like this would work.
    #screen.blit(dessert, (spot_(dessert_rand)x, spot_(dessert_rand)y)

    if wood_rand == 1:
        screen.blit(wood, (spot_1x, spot_1y))
    elif wood_rand == 2:
        screen.blit(wood, (spot_2x, spot_2y))
    elif wood_rand == 3:
        screen.blit(wood, (spot_3x, spot_3y))
    elif wood_rand == 4:
        screen.blit(wood, (spot_4x, spot_4y))
    elif wood_rand == 5:
        screen.blit(wood, (spot_5x, spot_5y))
    elif wood_rand == 6:
        screen.blit(wood, (spot_6x, spot_6y))
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question to explain, in words, what it is you're actually trying to achieve? It sounds as if you have seven images and you want to randomly assign them to seven different screen locations, in which case you can do this much, _much_ more simply than the code you've shown, but it's probably better if you tell us this than make us guess it from trying to interpret your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have seven images and you want to randomly assign them to seven different screen locations, put your locations into tuples in a list then use `random.shuffle` to randomise them:

```
import random
spots = [(0, 200), (100, 350), (300, 350), (400, 200), (300, 50), (100, 50), (200, 200)]
spots = random.shuffle(spots)
```

Then you can simply place the images at their locations one after another:

```
screen.blit(wood, spots[0]) 
screen.blit(brick, spots[1])
screen.blit(wheat, spots[2])
```

etc.

Or more concisely (and more 'Pythonic'):

```
images = [wood, brick, wheat, image4, image5, image6, image7]

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    screen.blit(image, spots[i])
```

Comment: close, but got an error. When i tried it in the console, it gave me this: 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: got it! Simply removed the "spot ="  before random.shuffle(spot) and it worked fine! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about lists? Looks like you could have a `spot` list containing tuples:

```
spot = [(0, 200), (100, 350), ...]
```

Then you can just replace the entire `if`-`elseif` chain by:

```
screen.blit(wood, spot[wood_rand - 1])
```

Note the `- 1`: lists in Python are 0-based. Best to take that into account when randomizing:

```
wood_rand = randint(0,5)
screen.blit(wood, spot[wood_rand])
```

(By the way, [dessert vs. desert](http://www.gingersoftware.com/english-online/spelling-book/confusing-words/desert-dessert), something tells me you mean the latter.)

Comment: That's really useful for shortening down at least one part of my code... The real problem is the giant if - elif block though.

Comment: Yeah i see that now. Kills 2 birds with 1 stone. Thanks. and i do mean the location, not the food.